# Should I edit my accepted answer?

Tags: support, edits, accepted-answer

Few days ago I [answered a newbie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345704/filter-form-in-rails/1346288#1346288), and the answer was accepted yesterday.

Today I woke up thinking of what poor an answer it was (I'm not normal, I fear): I wrote it to help the asker, who just needed a direction, and I indeed gave one, providing a working quick and dirty example. But now, thinking that the answer is going to remain, and to be found by google searches (and with my name on it!), I would like to improve it.

Few lines need to be changed and few other ones to be added.

What is the policy? Should I edit my answer now that it has been accepted? If so, should I edit it in a way that shows how the code was before my edit or not?

Also, will the asker (should he/she ever connect again) be notified about the edit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Absolutely edit the answer. Sometimes it's worth leaving an old version of the answer, but it really depends on the situation. (I sometimes have multiple "versions" within one answer; each has a bold title, and they're separated by horizontal rules.)

Don't worry too much about the asker - no, they won't get notified of the edit, but that's probably not too much of a problem. The long tail of other people finding your answer in the future is more important.

(As an extreme example of where editing is important, I recently answered a question incorrectly. It was accepted, but then the error was pointed out by another user who had posted a correct answer. I edited my answer to be correct, but requested that the asker deselect mine so that I could delete it as it was essentially superfluous.)

Comment: Did the other user get a badge for correcting Jon Skeet?

Answer (score 4):

It is totally encouraged to edit accepted answers to keep them up-to-date. I would make sure that the part which the questioner accepted is visible somehow (depends on the answer/question).
Leaving a comment to inform the questioner would be a nice thing!

Answer (score 2):

I've made edits to accepted answers before - but only in an additive or corrective fashion, never the overall answer.

For example, spelling, grammar, adding links, etc.